# Gamma Distribution for generating random numbers

Tags: python, random-variable, random-generation, gamma-distribution

I defined a gamma distribution with following parameters: shape,scale = 4.2503, 7037. This dribuation is used to generate random numbers. The random numbers will be recalculated to the x-asix value.

Now I have a question:
if I generate 460 random numbers at once, the histogram of those numbers doesn't look perfectly but it looks like a gamma distribution as I defined.

[image: 460 random numbers generated at once].

But if I generate 200, 200, 50 and 10 random numbers, and use the histogram to present all of them, I got such a wierd graph.

[image: 200-200-50-10]

I'm not very good at math. But can anyone explain why would the difference between these two methods are too big? Thank you very much.

This question is a very tiny part of my project. I have another discrete number list, which has only 60 numbers from 6800 to 112000. This 60 numbers are not equality divided in this range. I cut the discrete number list into 25 parts. So I have 26 bins. Every time when I generate a gamma random numbers, I use this number to find the corresponding bin in the discrete list. And then, use np.random to choose a number from [bin-1] to [bin]. Since the number is from a list, so it also have an index. The histogram above is actually the corresponding number.

Please use this link [Cars DataFrame](https://pastebin.com/hxPyCA24) to create the Cars Dataframe. Sorry for this inconvenience.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cats, bins = pd.cut(Cars['Preis'], 25, retbins=True)
list1 = Cars['Preis'].tolist()
for i in range(0,460):
    sample = np.random.gamma(shape, scale)
    while sample < min(list1) or sample > max(list1): # list1 is the discrete number list
        sample = np.random.gamma(shape, scale)
    bin_idx = np.digitize(sample,bins)
    if  0 < bin_idx < len(bins):
        for index, row in Cars.iterrows():
            if bins[bin_idx-1] < row.Preis <= bins[bin_idx]:
                choice_idx.append(index)
            else:
                pass
        if len(choice_idx) != 0:
            randomchoice = np.random.choice(choice_idx)
    else:
        target = min(list1, key=lambda x:abs(x-sample))
        randomchoice = list1.index(target)
    test.append(randomchoice)
```

Comment: could you post the code used to generate these? it looks fine for me using something like `np.concatenate([np.random.gamma(4.2503, scale=7.037, size=i) for i in [200, 200, 50, 10]])`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your implementation.  We'd need to see your code to be sure.  Here is mine:

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape,scale = 4.2503, 7037
Gamma = gamma(a = shape, scale = scale)
x = np.arange(1,100000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 3, nrows = 1, figsize = (20,5), sharex = True)
ax[0].plot(x, Gamma.pdf(x));

ax[1].hist(Gamma.rvs(460), edgecolor = 'white', bins = 50);


samps = np.concatenate([Gamma.rvs(j) for j in [200, 200, 50 , 10]])
ax[2].hist(samps, edgecolor = 'white', bins = 50);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my post.

Comment: @WJPING You should edit your code into a minimal working example.  We don't have access to the `Cars` data frame, so we can't run or edit your example

Comment: Hi @DemetriPananos I use a link to share the Cars Dataframe. Hope you will check. Thank you